# SUMPRODUCT formula with delimiter, exclude blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have excel formula for sumproduct data with delimiter, and it works fine when there are not blank cells but cannot work if there are any blanks.

example bellow:

[image: This is with all values]

and not with E4 included.

[image: this is the second image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `IFERROR()` this can be resolved and fixed:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--TRIM(LEFT(B4:E4,FIND("/",B4:E4)-1)),0))
```

---

And there are obvious reasons that is returning an error, because it cant find the delimiter `/` here, hence it returns the error.

[image]

---

```
=FIND("/",E4)
```

---

`FIND()` function returns error when it cant find the value/text it is searching for.

---

For your version of excel the separator will be different.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--TRIM(LEFT(B4:E4;FIND("/";B4:E4)-1));0))
```

---

BTW, `MS365` users can use `TEXTBEFORE()` and dont need the `IFERROR()`

[image]

---

```
=SUM(--TEXTBEFORE(B4:E4,"/",,,,0))
```

---

If there are no leading or trailing spaces, then the `TRIM()` function can be excluded.

Comment: I used your formula             =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--TRIM(LEFT(B4:E4;FIND("/";B4:E4)-1));0))      but I got 1, instead of 13

Comment: @CiricAleksandar assume you are not using `MS365` hence this would need to hit the `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` while exiting the edit mode.

Comment: Omg, correct. Sorry for my mistakes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Its not your fault, i should have mentioned that in before. Thought you were using `MS365`

Comment: It should be noted that with sumproduct you don't normally need to use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`  since sumproduct performs arraylike calculations.  However, when if functions are used with array like functions then `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` must be used.

Comment: @CiricAleksandar if the answer has worked you may like to accept it by clicking the tick mark beside it